# How to build a regex which match RFC2396 for URI/URL?

Tags: java, regex, url, uri

I'm not so into Regex and after many search on google, i can't really see the right solution to my problem.
I want to build a regex to match with RFC 2396. I come across with this one : [regex Test](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2088&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
I tested it on https://regex101.com/ but it's look really complicated.

So my question is there any easy to read regex for filtering URI/URL after RFC 2396 ?

Comment: Use the URL/URI class not a regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a less complicated regex in the official documentation of RFC 2396

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

Please visit [tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#appendix-B) for more detail. There you will find a step by step explanation of the regular expression.

Comment: Great! Thank you

Comment: Updated 2005, but I think it's the exact same regex, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-B.